# Writing Issues With QTextStream

Tags: qt, qfile, qtextstream

```
QFile vfile(file);
if(!vfile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)) qDebug() << "FILE COULDN NOT BE OPENED";
QTextStream stream(&vfile);

stream << "Hello" << "=";
vfile.write("132");
```

Output to File - 132Hello=

In the above example, I write the data in 2 different ways but when I see the file I found some this type of result that while using "write()" the data within write() printed first instead of the above statements is displayed in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream data is cached for a time (which is typical of writing to streams in general, eg. `stdout` and such). You can flush the stream data to be sure it is all written before writing to the file via a different method.

```
stream << "Hello=" << flush;
vfile.write("123");
```

Also see *manipulator functions* list in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#details

Writing an end-of-line character (`endln` or `\n`) will also flush the stream buffer.